# issue when running update on a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
   UPDATE p
   SET p.isShown = 1
   FROM  `shop_picture` p
   INNER JOIN  `shop` s 
   ON p.shop_id = s.id
   WHERE p.`isShown` = 0
   AND p.`deletedAt` IS NULL 
   AND p.`isLocked` = 1
   AND s.`isLocked` = 1
  AND s.`expirydate` <  '2014-10-28 00:00:00';
```

when trying to run it I always get an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM shop_picture` p INNER JOIN `shop` s O' at line 3
```

I don't understand what the error is. Anyone care to give a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE `shop_picture` p
   INNER JOIN `shop` s 
   ON p.shop_id = s.id
   SET p.isShown = 1
   WHERE p.`isShown` = 0
   AND p.`deletedAt` IS NULL 
   AND p.`isLocked` = 1
   AND s.`isLocked` = 1
  AND s.`expirydate` <  '2014-10-28 00:00:00';
```